# Maintaining Hourly Tables NoSql

Tags: redis, cassandra

I need to maintain hourly tables that store a lot of counters. I plan to keep just the current hourly table and previous hour's table at any time as older data isnt important to me.

For ex. if the time is 4 30 pm, I will have an hourly table from 3:00 - 4:00 pm and the current hourly table 4:00 - 4:30 pm. Once the time crosses 5:00 pm, I delete the 3:00-4:00 pm table.

Each hourly table will grow to a maximum size of 7-8 gb, and the queries are highly concurrent and write oriented (10:1 writes:reads, 20,000 writes per second and 2000 reads per second on an average).

As the size of data is small ( max 10gb in my db) and all queries are counter increments, should I go for a key val store like Cassandra(counter columns) or an in memory db like Redis. ( I plan to partition the db to split the immense write load)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a task for in-memory processing: HashMap is much faster than the fastest of databases. So, I'd recommend to look at hazelcast (http://www.hazelcast.com/) or storm (https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm).

Periodic dumping of counters to some in-memory DB (like Redis or Memcached) might be made to make querying simpler. But it's doable purely in memory, without any DB back-end at all.

Cassandra looks like an overkill for that task: it's amazing when you need to store terabytes of data forever in replicated and highly available way, but it's not trivial to set it up for heavy load if you never did it before.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My only concern for doing it purely in memory was if my machine can handle the immense query load ( 30000 writes per second, 3000 reads per second at peak). Also, assuming I have to scale to lets say 100000 writes per sec, wouldnt it be easier with redis or cassandra?

Comment: Redis also provides an expire/TTL for keys that could automate cleanup of old data for you.

Comment: Amaron, both hazelcast and storm scale perfectly to tens and hundreds of machines. My point was that if in-memory solution is 10 times faster than DB and scales equally good, you'll need 10 times less machines for the same load. And I think in-memory data grid is easier to deploy and scale than a database.